# Custom scroll-bar for body on bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I try to use best solution for bootstrap custom scroll-bar but so far nothing special:|
I want to be able to replace default browser scroll-bar on body and inside on other elements like panels or wells, textarea ...
I found [**this plugin**](http://enscrollplugin.com/) and woks just fine but if I want to replace body scroll is not working as in other cases.
Am I not doing something right or ... can someone explain me why is not working for `<body>` or if can just suggest me other plugins **except:** `jQuery slimScroll, malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin, jScrollPane` because I already tested and aren't good for my project.

**[Here is a small fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PGuB5/235/)**

ty

Comment: which browser are you using? When I view your fiddle in Chrome the `<body>` has the same custom scrollbar as `#scrollbox3`.

Comment: @Starscream1984 yes you can see the body scrollbar but is not working :| In all browsers is the same behavior. Try to drag up and down.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I see what you mean now - looks to me like you can't really use this javascript scroll solution on the `<body>` tag as it gets confused by the hidden parts of the other scrolled elements.

I would suggest wrapping everything in a `<div id=bodyDiv>`, styling it to use only the available window space and then adding the scrollbar to that to simulate the scroll being on `<body>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/W4JKM/

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I will use your suggestion :)